# What is UAT Protocol?

Tags: documentation, user-acceptance-testing, acceptance-testing

I've just written a `UAT (User Acceptance Testing)` script specifying all of the use cases step by step (quite standard).

However, the customer is asking us for a `UAT` protocol and we have no clue on what he means by that.

Can anyone explain and/or provide some kind of template or what sections this document should contain?

Comment: How about asking the customer what they mean by it ? That will get a much more useful result than getting people on the internet to guess at what your customer is requesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a customer asks you for something using words that you don't understand, you must ask for clarification.

I'm guessing that the customer wants to understand how the whole UAT process will work - who does what, how, and when.  But that's just a guess.

The term "UAT Protocol" could mean anything to this particular customer.  Guessing and hoping for the best just doesn't make sense.  Be honest and ask for an explanation so as to best meet the customer's needs.

Comment: Agreed.  If you are worried about looking stupid in front of the customer, you can always say, "At our company, when we say UAT Protocol, we mean...", and then say something that sounds reasonable to you (and that you are prepared to actually do).  I think Joe's guess is reasonable, but you should decide for yourself.

Comment: I also believe he means UAT plan or how the process will work, however user246 is right and our main concern was too look stupid :P I will ask the customer about the meaning. thanks (Phil K. maybe because I am not a native english speaker but your comment sounds kinda rude to me, specially in a forum where people ask for help [ok, your comment is right but sounds rude to me])

Comment: @momo I cannot speak for Phil, but I do not think he intended to be rude.  Many questions in SQA fall into this category: someone uses a term when communicating with the OP, and then OP asks us what that person meant.  The answer is always the same: we know how we use that term, but our opinion does not matter.  If you really need an answer, the best policy is to say something like, "I am sorry, but you used a term that people use in different ways.  What do *you* mean when you use that term?"

Comment: @momo Re-reading my comment I can see maybe why it was taken as rude. It could have been phrased more politely but the message is still the same - first ask the customer rather than a bunch of strangers with no real insight into your context. Blunt rather than rude :)

Answer (score 0):

UAT Protocol is a final document, based on successful results(passed) of all test cases for each module of the system. It should be signed by PM of the developer site and PM from the user site. As appendixes of the UAT Protocol should be the results of test cases for each module, signed by user responsible for the module.